# When are constexpr objects constructed?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

When are `constexpr` objects constructed relative to non-`constexpr` non-local objects with static storage duration? Do they start their life prior to initialization of any other objects, i.e., prior to dynamic initialization?

I'm contemplating whether it would be reasonable to have a [`string_literal` class (live example)](http://ideone.com/Vs1VCh) which is used, e.g., to compare `std::string`s against certain keywords:

```
class string_literal
{
    // private members
public:
    constexpr string_literal(char const* b);
    bool operator== (std::string const& other) const;
    bool operator!= (std::string const& other) const;
    // other member functions
};

constexpr string_literal hello("hello");
void f(std::string const& s) {
    if (s == hello) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Since the `string_literal` could parse the string-literal at compile-time to locate the first null-character, I could imagine that these comparisons can be made faster than comparing a `std::string` against a string-literal. However, to be safe it is necessary that the `hello` object is readily constructed when the first constructor is executed at run-time during static initialization: otherwise these objects could be accidentally accessed when they are not, yet, constructed.

Comment: A string litreral class is useful for avoiding throwing away type information, both the array size and the fact that it's an object with static storage duration. Expressing that explicitly is about the only recourse with C++11, since the distinguishing feature of string literals, the decays to pointer to non-`const` has been removed. And that's what I use such class for, but I don't quite see the efficiency aspect that you're talking about?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: When comparing a string literal to a `std::string` it is necessary to find the null character as it doesn't have to be the last character in the literal (e.g., `"hello\0world"`). I'm not saying there is a speed advantage but I could imagine that there could be a speed advantage with the `string_literal` class as it can compute the `end` at compile time (see the [live example](http://ideone.com/Vs1VCh)).

Comment: Oh. Well I'm pretty tired at the moment (early morning, new year, all that). So. But anyway, Happy New Year! :-)

Comment: @DietmarKühl \OT fashion: That's an effin' nice hat, isn't it? Arrrr ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: \OT fashion: it is ;-) I like this new one even better ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the C++11 standard the order of initialization of non-local variables is discussed in §3.6.2 “Initialization of non-local variables”.

First **static initialization** is performed, then **dynamic initialization**.

Static initialization consists of **zero-initialization**  followed by **constant-initialization**. Zero-initialization is just what it sounds like. Constant-initialization is new in C++11, and §3.6.2/2 specifies that it's performed

> - if each full-expression (including implicit conversions) that appears in the initializer of a reference with static or thread storage duration is a constant expression (5.19) and the reference is bound to an lvalue designating an object with static storage duration or to a temporary (see 12.2);
> - if an object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constructor call, if the constructor is a `constexpr` constructor, if all constructor arguments are constant expressions (including conversions), and if, after function invocation substitution (7.1.5), every constructor call and full-expression in the mem-initializers and in the *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members is a constant
>     expression;
> - if an object with static or thread storage duration is not initialized by a constructor call and if every full-expression that appears in its initializer is a constant expression.

So, the second point is where a `constexpr` object is potentially initialized, as the last part of static initialization, and essentially it happens if everything is `constexpr` so that it can be known at compile time.

And yes, as part of the static initialization this happens before dynamic initialization.